# matplotlib legend: remove handles, keep labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I plot many points in different colors and I want the legend to contain only the names in different colors, like this:

```
for x,y,c in my_data:
    axes.plot(x,y,color=c)
legend = axes.legend(loc="best", labels=my_labels)
for text in legend.get_texts():
    text.set_color(label2color[text.get_text()])
```

this results in a legend where the labels are in the correct colors but the handles show lines with points the colors of the first few points:

[image]

I want to remove the handles completely so that the only text in the legend is the labels.

Comment: By setting the length of the handle in the legend to 0, the handle will no longer be displayed. You can also set the color of the legend text to be the same as the color of the line by specifying the color of the labels. No color change is required in the loop process. `legend = ax.legend(loc="best", handlelength=0, labels=my_labels, labelcolor='linecolor')`

Comment: @r-beginners: thank you, but your suggestion eliminates the _line_ but not the _point_.

Comment: @r-beginners: as for `labelcolor='linecolor'` - this is exactly the ***opposite*** of what I want: the color of the label is correct, the color of the handle is _wrong_ (note the 3 blue lines in the legend in the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating empty handles **and** specifying their emptiness turned out to be the answer:

```
legend = axes.legend(loc="best", labels=my_labels,
                     handles=[axes.plot([],[])[0] for _ in my_labels],
                     handlelength=0, handleheight=0, handletextpad=0)
```